# TD of the Table element break into new line

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

So this is an email template which you can not use modern front-end technologies. What I have to make is write 3 columned lines.

They all have to be in the same TR because in mobile, columns gonna be 2. So if I find a way to break these into new line, I am gonna adapt that with mobile too.

Baicly i need this,

https://snag.gy/QwgPfi.jpg

Into this (on mobile)

https://snag.gy/5LEtfD.jpg

I have the structure as:

```
<tr>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
</tr>
```

What I need to do is make 3 columned lines. The `td` above the `tr` has a width, so table inside has 100%. So how to break into a new line WITHOUT using `tr`'s?

Comment: You could divide you table with <tbody> tag. Give different measures.

Answer (score 0):

Float the `td` and add a width

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width:100%;
  }

td {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've been building 3 column layouts using the `tr` tag. Saves a lot of time messing about with widths and align. Just add tables within the `tr` tags for content/spacer

media queries for `width:100%` and `display:block` will stack the three columns (left to right) and the spacer will also stack.

example:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <!-- left column -->
        <th width="180" class="block width100"></th>
        <!-- space -->
        <th class="block"></th>
        <!-- middle column -->
        <th width="180" class="block width100"></th>
        <!-- space -->
        <th class="block"></th>
        <!-- right column -->
        <th width="180" class="block width100"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need the last th to go next line, not with 33% but with 50%. Does this useful that way ?